# Display contents of CSV file in table with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file, csv

My requirement is simple. I need a button that'll open a csv file and display the contents in  a table of rows/columns. What's the best way to do that in MVC?

Answer (score 0):

Use the built in [CSV parser in .NET](http://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/built-in-net-csv-parser/) to parse the CSV file into an array, then use that array as the model for your view and render the table with a simple `foreach` loop.

Comment: Thanks for that. How do I have the user click teh button to open file and read into this table. My question really is this: The view is based on a model that has a lot of attributes of which one is a IEnumerable<names>. The file the user chooses contains names. The save button on teh form will post the entire model. How can I have the button call a controller action that does nothing but reads the file-content to the list (as I cannot access the list in the controller). Please let me know if I'm unclear.

Comment: Set a specific value and name on that button and make sure to add a property with the same name to your view model. Then you can detect if that button was clicked in the action method.

Comment: Apologies, I was not clear. Here's my issue: All I need is a button(not text box for file name). Once the user clicks on the button, a window opens to choose a file and automatically populates the list on the view. Now, the view has a model(say, Employee). This list(say, paychecks) is only one of the model properties. Questions 1) How can I have a @Html.ActionLink open a file and pass that to a controller 2) Once the controller finishes reading the file contents, it has to populate the list of paycheks. So, I cannot return a view of 'paychecks', as the view model is of type Employee.

Comment: Being new to MVC, I was confused initially when I asked this question. But am clear now:1) How can I post the file contents to a controller action immediately after the file is chosen(without a submit button)

2) How do I populate the list from the controller action without returning a view (as returning a view would ask for another .cshtml)

Comment: That's two totally different questions than the first one you asked. Please post them as two new questions (you can post a link to them in a comment here if you want and I'll have a look at them).

Comment: Thank you. Here's the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894500/mvc-upload-file